# SQL Server SQL to PostgreSQL SQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I need to convert the following SQL server code to PostgreSQL code.
Any help would be appreciated.

SQL Server SQL:

```
CAST(DATEADD(ww,DATEDIFF(ww,0,trans_date),-1)as date) as week
```

Comment: Including your PostgreSQL attempt will greatly help those you are asking for help from help you; we can't correct your attempt if we don't know what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what that code does is to "round" the value of `trans_date` to the beginning of the week. In Postgres you can do that using the `date_trunc()` function:

```
date_trunc('week', trans_date)
```

Note that this always returns a `timestamp`, if you need a real `date` value, cast the result:

```
date_trunc('week', trans_date)::date
```

If it should be the day *before* the beginning of the week, just subtract one day from the result:

```
 date_trunc('week', trans_date)::date  - 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
This worked perfectly!
I actually needed that last one so just wanted to add "INTERVAL" which was missing from the code.

date_trunc('week', trans_date)::date  - INTERVAL '1 day'